# How to change ipch path in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I saw that VS2010 creates some files in the solution folder(.sdf, .suo, .ipch, etc). Is it possible to change the folder where these files are created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The `ipch` folder is created by the IntelliSense system and it's location cannot be changed on a per-solution basis. However, you can have VS 2010 store all of your projects' `ipch` folders in your `%TEMP%\VC++` folder. Select **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **C/C++** > **Advanced**. Once there, you'll see a **Fallback Location** section. Change **Always Use Fallback Location** to **True**. Leave **Fallback Location** blank and it will put them in your `%TEMP%` folder. Once you've changed that, you can remove your `ipch` folder and your `*.sdf` & `*.opensdf` files. They will be recreated in the fall-back location. Note, you may want to backup those files if you're picky about the window layout, etc for the project.

I learned this from this [MSDN Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/09/intellisense-browsing-options-in-vc-2010.aspx). Also note that a `*.suo` file will still be created in the same location as your solution. I'm not sure how to change that.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it did not work, possibly because my temp folder is on a ramdisk formatted with FAT32. (upon startup visual studio was popping up a message saying intellisense would not be available due to inability to create some file there.) I specified the fallback location to be C:\ and this got rid of the error message, but nothing new showed up on the root of my drive C:.  A search for *.ipch yields nothing. The build is very fast though, which probably means that the precompiled header file is being used. I am totally confused.