# Can we specify where the *.VC.db files are saved?

Tags: intellisense

This question explained what the *.VC.db files are:

[What is the *.VC.db file in Visual Studio projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407386/what-is-the-vc-db-file-in-visual-studio-projects-and-can-i-safely-delete-it)

Now I would like to know how to specify which folder that those files are put into, or make them hidden.

I regularly make a backup of my source and project files, and I don't want to waste my time and disk space backing up temporary files.

In one folder, I have a few projects that add up to 150 kB, and the two VC.db files are 84 MB.

Isn't there some way to specify where the VC.db files are placed, as we can do with the object files?

Answer (score 7):

I just discovered that the way to set the folder for the *.VC.DB files is the same as for the IPCH files, as described here:

[How to change ipch path in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315681/how-to-change-ipch-path-in-visual-studio-2010)

I also specified a folder for the "fallback location" rather than leave it blank, which sends the files to whatever you have set for your **%TEMP%** folder.