# How do I extract source code files from Visual Studio pollution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-c++-2015

In a directory where source code resides, there are also Visual Studio related files, like *.user, *.vcxproj. And `Debug` and `Release` folders.

I would like to change project directory layout so it looks like this:

For example, the project is named ProjectX.

In the ProjectX main folder, there would be only two subfolders:

- ProjectX/Source
- ProjectX/Build

In ProjectX/Source there would be all source code files, but nothing else.

In ProjectX/Build there would be all Visual Studio-related files.

How can I do it?

Comment: What in the names of all the gods is a "pollutation"? Your name indicates that you are likely an English speaker, and at least your question indicates you have a fair command of the language. Surely you have seen this, so why have you not bothered to correct it? It isn't even a word, so I can't see the blame being with auto-complete/correct.

Comment: @ProfK Thanks, I have corrected it. I didn't know that such word does not exist. BTW: John is random name chosen when I was creating this account, English is not my native language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the vcxproj into the build directory, move the vcxproj into the build directory.

To move your source files under a source directory, move your source files under a source directory.

After either or both of the above steps, you'll need to re-add the files to Visual Studio, but I'm sure you knew that. Visual Studio isn't psychic and can't guess where your files are if you move everything around.

The SDF file can be moved by asking Stack Overflow how to move the SDF file: *[How to change ipch path in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315681/how-to-change-ipch-path-in-visual-studio-2010)*

Visual Studio 2015 should not be creating .user files any more. Perhaps you're not fully updated?

At this point you have everything you wanted, even though it's weird. Except for portable projects, people aren't generally moving their vcxproj files. The vcxproj file is typically considered the root of the project, just like a makefile would be; under it is build and source.

Now let me give you advice. Don't do all of that. Do this instead:

Move your source files in a source directory. Now in Visual Studio, go to project properties and change *Output Directory* and *Intermediate Directory* to `$(ProjectDir)Build\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`

Now you have one Build directory instead of a Debug and Release directory. That means a lot to some people. It means more to people with more build configurations.